# Update column from other column of same table

Tags: oracle11g

I have following table abc

```
col1         col2    
-------------------
abc.837      
efg
hij.clm.837
klm.clm
```

In above table i want to update column col2 with the values of col1.
desired output is

```
col1         col2    
-------------------
abc.837      abc.837     
efg          efg.837
hij.clm.837  hij.clm.837
klm.clm      klm.clm.837
```

it means values in col2 should be same as col1 wherever it dosent find .837 in the end
of the string, it should append .837 at the end of the string.
its urgent. reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
update your_table
set col2 = case when regexp_like(col1, '\.837$') then col1 else col1 ||'.837' end
```